# Правильно ли настроен nginx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

Правильно ли настроен nginx?
Сайт на nextjs запущен на 3000 порту со своим доменом. Бекенд написан на express. И запущен на localhost:3001. Админка для сайта на реакте, раздается express с localhost:3001. Я делаю так: перехожу на сайт/admin вижу пустую страницу и в network не загрузились css\js
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]